# Microphone level too low on iMac to use it for Google Docs dictation even at max setting

Tags: macos

Encouraged by a story I saw the other day I am trying to learn how to use Google Docs via voice dictation.  I can get it to work, but only if I speak into the iMac internal microphone from about three inches away from the screen.

If I'm sitting the usual distance away the internal mic can't pick up my voice at all.  I checked in System Preferences and I have the internal mic at its highest input setting.

To get around this I bought a cheap used microphone and headset but discovered that my iMac has no separate mic input plug and I gather I need a special four-wire connector that uses the headphone jack to do both headphone and mic together.  I can't find that locally.

I'm hoping someone can tell me if this is normal behavior for an iMac or if there's some other volume setting to adjust so I don't have to lean over my computer to talk to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote from Apple. This is easy for you to fix.

> Audio in: Some Mac computers include built-in microphones, or an audio in port. If your Mac doesn't have an audio in port, you can use an adapter like a USB-to-audio adapter to connect an external audio source.

<sup>Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201736</sup>

Comment: When quoting content from elsewhere, make sure to include a link to the original source.